# Woocommerce - Product variations in stock

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce, variant, stock

I have question about Woocommerce product variations. When I have variable product with three parameters/variant. I need to make a **SPECIAL VARIANT showed only if the first or second variant is in stock**. When customer buy both variants, the SPECIAL must hide. SPECIAL variant can not be the only one visible for example:

```
VARIANT 1 - 1x in stock
VARIANT 2 - 1x in stock
VARIANT SPECIAL - in stock only if V1 or V2 is in stock
```

**Customer buy V1:**

```
VARIANT 1 - HIDE (out of stock)
VARIANT 2 - 1x in stock
VARIANT SPECIAL - in stock only if V1 or V2 is in stock
```

**Another customer buy V2:**

```
VARIANT 1 - HIDE (out of stock)
VARIANT 2 - HIDE (out of stock)
VARIANT SPECIAL - HIDE (both variants is out of stock)
```

[IMAGE OF VARIANTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFHBc.png)

I do not know if I explained well, sorry for my English.

Any solutions for this? Any hook, snippet or plugin?

I'll be glad for any advice, Jakob.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need the function `is_in_stock` and some `if` for each variations.
Here is my example.

```
        if ($product_stock1=$variation_product->is_in_stock())
        {
        echo "Variacion 1 en Stock";
        }

        if ($product_stock2=$variation_product2->is_in_stock())
        {
        echo "Variacion 2 en Stock";
        }
        if (($product_stock1)||($product_stock2))
        {
        echo "Variacion 3 Visible";
        }
```

The code has been tested and is functional. The theme I use to test this code is Storefront.
Depending on which page you are going to display this, it depends the hook.

Comment: Hi, I dont know if you understand me. I dont want call echo or any text, i want only to hide VARIANT 3, when V1 and V2 is out of stock.

[link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFHBc.png

Do you have any snippet, which I copy to functions.php in child theme? I use template Flatsome.

Comment: I know. Thats why I put you an example for that. You dont specify the theme or the page.
The echos will not display if the condition is not meet. Including the Variation 3 who was your specific condition, hiding it.
It was a basic example to understand the reasoning you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I am a begginer in PHP. I dont know how this code edit to my version and add to functions.php. I thought that i need add_filter or action to add this snippet to functions.

Comment: Can you send me full code that i copy to functions.php? Template is: http://flatsome3.uxthemes.com/

Comment: Have you tried to adapt the code I show? Have you tried some other code?